# on listitem click colour should remain same

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

I am using `listview` I have following `xml` with shape to set in `listitem`

**one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#D5F4FF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#979797"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFA500"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#979797"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Now,by default,I want to set **`one.xml`** to my listitem and when user click on `listitem` it should set **`two.xml`** and it still remain same,but its not working
I have already tried with `listselector` property of `listview`.

**CustomAdapter**

```
 private class CustomAdapterGiftsharealert extends BaseAdapter {
        //  String [] result;
        Context context;
        // int [] imageId;
        private ArrayList<String> listData;
        private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public CustomAdapterGiftsharealert(Context mainActivity, ArrayList<String> listData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            context=mainActivity;
            this.listData=listData;

            inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return listData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder
        {
            TextView tv;

            public TextView tvbday;

            public TextView tvrelation;
            public LinearLayout linr;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Holder holder=new Holder();
            View rowView;
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_frndsfmly, null);

            holder.linr=(LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.linear_listitem_frndsmly);
            holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frndsfamly_name);
            holder.tvbday=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frndsfamly_bady);
            holder.tvrelation=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frndsfamly_realtion);
            holder.tvbday=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.frndsfamly_bady);
            holder.tv.setText(listData.get(position));
            holder.tvbday.setText(bdatedata.get(position));


            //  holder.tvrelation.setText(testlist.get(position));



            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

Comment: still remain same means what???

Comment: @MrsEd in java i dint set any background

Comment: @Clairvoyant meand if turn orange from black while clicking,,,then orange must set as background until selection of another item

Comment: where you are changing the background??

Comment: i set listselector property in my listview..

Answer (score 0):

Use below `selector xml` name it **view_selector.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/view_pressed" />
        </shape></item>

    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/view_pressed" />
        </shape></item>

    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/view_normal" />
        </shape></item>
</selector>
```

And add colors in `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="view_pressed">#FFA500</color>
<color name="view_normal">#D5F4FF</color>
```

Suppose for an example you are having a custom adapter which having a layout you can set it as `background` in root tag. as an example:

**custom_adapter_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/view_selector" >

    <TextView 
        style="@style/textviewstyle_Medium"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="@string/textview1"/>

      <TextView 
        style="@style/textviewstyle_small"
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/textview2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but where and how to set ??

Comment: i have custom adapter

Comment: In your `custom adapter` layout set the selector

Comment: you mean listitems view or custom adapter java code?

Comment: @Jolly set this as background for you listitems view.

Comment: @Yasoda you mean in my listitem i need to set as background??

Comment: @Jolly yes in xml file you can directly set background

Comment: @Clairvoyant on touch i get orange color..but after relese touch orange color gone..i dont want to it gone

Comment: @Yasoda can you tell about above comment

Comment: @Clairvoyant can you tell

Comment: @Jollywrite this in listitems layout android:background="@drawable/selectorfile"

Comment: @Jolly - I have edited my answer and gave an example using xml for how to set background in adapter layout.

Comment: and did you read question that..after selection colour is again changing..thats what i dont want..:(

Comment: In custom layout xml just put a line in your root tag here in my example its `LinearLayout` so i have set it as `android:background="@drawable/view_selector"`

Comment: Hey yasoda, your from ahmedabad?? I have to ask you something

Answer (score 0):

For the list selector to work you need to set the `ListeView` choice mode:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

and override

```
@Override 
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Make the newly clicked item the currently selected one. 
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

> **Note:** Make sure the layout for the items do support selection, or use the android layout file: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1`